# SocketUseSSL property in config file for quickfix c++

Tags: c++, ssl, quickfix, fix-protocol

I've noted that `SocketUseSSL` is not respected in c++. I have a quickfix engine (acceptor) with ssl. And I am trying to connect to it via quickfix c++. I added `SocketUseSSL=Y` property to the config file but it is not respected.

Are there any other properties I need to use in conjunction with the `SocketUseSSL` ?

I wrote my own ssl proxy with openssl but I was checking just in case if we can use this option.

Comment: Hi, I noticed that the property SocketUseSSL is available only on quickfix/J. What version of Quickfix are you using?

Comment: @stexcec I am using quickfix 1.13.3

Comment: The c# version doesn't support this property, only the Java one

Comment: Ok, thanks then I'll keep my SSL proxy library as is...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to answer my own question.

There are no SocketUseSSL property in config file for quickfix c++ as of now. I logged https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/issues/31 to address the issue.